# ImportError: cannot import name 'style_from_dict' for RASA interactive learning.Incompatible prompt-toolkit version

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, importerror, chatbot, rasa-core

I am trying to train the flow of dialog using interactive learning in Rasa Core using Jupyter notebook.

code snippet:

```
### interactive learning 
import logging
from rasa_core import utils, train
from rasa_core.training import interactive

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def train_agent():
    return train.train_dialogue_model(domain_file="domain.yml",
                                      stories_file="data/stories.md",
                                      output_path="models/dialogue",
                                      policy_config='policy_config.yml'
                                      )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    utils.configure_colored_logging(loglevel="INFO")
    agent = train_agent()
    logger.info("This example does not include NLU data."
                "Please specify the desired intent with a preceding '/', e.g."
                "'/greet' .")
    interactive.run_interactive_learning(agent)
```

Initially I was getting:

> "Token not found error" pointing to 
>   "from prompt_toolkit.token import Token"

I downgraded to `prompt_toolkit==1.0.14` and tried running the code.

Getting:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'style_from_dict'

I feel there is a version incompatibility for `prompt_toolkit` in `rasa-core` and `ipython`.
Currently using `rasa-core==0.12.3` and `ipython==7.2.0`.

Do I need to downgrade `IPython`?
Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

The errors were resolved after downgrading to ipython 6.0.0.